# Face recognition with keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Below is my face recognition model. I get several issues while training my training data on it. My dataset contains images of me. When I train it, validation accuracy is 100%. And also its prediction is bad. What can I do to solve this problem?

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models 

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',
    input_shape = (150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

print(model.summary())

from keras import optimizers

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
    metrics=['acc'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (150,150),
    batch_size=20)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size = (150,150),
    batch_size=20)

history = model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch = 100,
epochs = 3,
validation_data = validation_generator,
validation_steps = 50)

model.save('/home/monojit/Desktop/me3.h5')
```

Answer (score 1):

How large is the dataset that is being used? A small dataset might be the problem, or your model architecture if the model is not generalizing well. Also, you might look at image augmentation using the `ImageDataGenerator`, see the blog post that i'll link to in a bit.

If the purpose of this project is to get as high accuracy as possible, without explicitly learning how CNN and their different layers work, then i would suggest the following. As you are working with images, you might not want to re-invent the wheel. Go on and take a pre-trained convolutional neural network, then train that on your imaged. This will yield you way higher accuracy with less epochs, than an untrained network. A great blog post can be found here [Keras Cats vs dogs](https://jkjung-avt.github.io/keras-tutorial/).
Now this tutorial is cats vs dogs. But you can use (almost, depending on your input images) the exact same code for your problem.

Comment: @deKeijzerMy dataset contains images of me. The no. of training samples present are only 2500. If this no. is low, how do I make my model accurate?